# When creating website to host WCF service, edit wcf config gives "no service found"

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WCF and have what I think should be a simple question.  I created a solution that contains a WCF service library, and a website to host the service.  In the website I reference the service library proj, so the  service.dll is in my website's /bin.  I edited the .svc file in the website to use the referenced project's service, but when I right click on the web.config and choose "Edit WCF Configuration" under services it says "No services defined".

I am following this tutorial, 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVPXLF-g4Ws&feature=related
and when he does the "Edit WCF Configuration" step, the referenced service is listed.

He is using vs2008, I am using vs2010.  Am I missing something?  I am hope I have provided is enough info to get some answers.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same exact issue, but I recreated my WCF service in VS2008 and it worked.
I would love to know why the configuration doesn't recognize the service in VS2010.

*Update*: 
I edited the `web.config` file replacing the `System.ServiceModel` section with the one from the WCF Library `app.config`.

Answer (score 0):

At first there are no services defined *in the configuration file* (web.config) - it's defined in the .svc file, and if you try to access it, it will even work (if you're using .net 4.0), as WCF will add a default endpoint if no configuration is found for the service.

If you want to customize the configuration for your service, select "Create a New Service...", then browse to the /bin directory and select the class library DLL. Then you can select the service class, and proceed from there.