# Can't define the endpoint after creating my WCF

Tags: wcf, ssis

I wanna learn WCF so I decided to try out creating some application that uses it. Well what I have in mind is I have 2 databases and I wanna create also an SSIS custom data source extension that calls the web service and passes the data (from one database) to an SSIS ADO.Net Data source (into the second database).

Now I created the 2 databases using SQL Server with one table in each. Then I  Added a Connection in Visual Studio and then specified the server instance. (didn't create any .mdf files). I added this connectionString in the Web.Config file

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbconnection" connectionString=" 
         Data Source = SARE-VAIO;
         Integrated Security = true; 
         Initial Catalog = Database1"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I wrote my service which basically populates Database1 with data, I wanted to define the endpoints but when I clicked on the "Edit WCF Configuration" it says 'No Service' is defined? What possibly am I doing wrong here? I want to create an error free service to be able to use it as a source in the SSIS package.

PS. My service has a basicHttpsBinding

UPDATE: I'm using VS 2012 with .Net Framework 4.5

UPDATE 2:
I skipped the endpoint definition for now and went ahead with testing and deploying my WCF. When I invoke the service it says the following error

```
  Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; 
  the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. 
  Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, 
  restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.
```

Here is my web.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="dbconnection" connectionString="Data Source = SARE-VAIO; Integrated        Security = true; Initial Catalog = Database1"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
      </protocolMapping>    
      <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"       multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

      <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

  </configuration>
```

Comment: You're not providing enough info for us to help you (without guessing at the problem). In addition, perhaps [this question is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286662/when-creating-website-to-host-wcf-service-edit-wcf-config-gives-no-service-fou)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as him I followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlyND7b2-YA but I can't define the endpoints and I guess this is causing problem when I wanna test my service. (It says Service is Offline) I didn't find any help in the other question.

Comment: While you're debugging turn includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true. It will give you better error details.

Comment: I did so but I still get the same error message. Here is the error details: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:52622/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). Do I need to do something with the Binding in the config file?

Comment: I invoked the service again and this time I got this in the error details: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:52622/Service.svc. I'm pretty sure now it has to do with the endpoints so if someone could help me configure those I would be really thankful

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions

(1) Why WCF configuration editor shows 'No service is defined' error : Your web.config does not have any services and endpoints defined explicitly (Note: When you host this in IIS you will still get some endpoints added due to the defaults endpoint feature. But config editor tool shows only explicitly defined endpoints). That's the reason the config editor tool shows this message. But you can use the tool to add services and endpoints.

(2) After deploying the service see if the service successfully activated. You can do this by browsing to the metadata URL (your config has metadata enabled). Make sure your service WSDL help page and WSDL shows up fine. If not fix that issue first.

(3) If you are looking a default https endpoint after hosting it in IIS, make sure your IIS has https binding configured with an SSL certificate.

Hope this helps!

Thanks!